# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name in 2.4.1 Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

## main Class:

```
package *.*.*;


@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## DBUtils.java

```
package *.*.*.dataaccess.dbutils;
    @Service
    public class DBUtils {
    
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;
    
        public UserEntity getUserEntityById(String id) {
    
            return userRepository.findById(id);
        }
    }
```

## Repository Class:

```
package *.*.*.dataaccess.repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, UserIdentity> {

    UserEntity findById(String id);
}
```

`and also UserEntity java class is in package *.*.*.dataaccess.dao;`

## Test Class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserApplicationTests {

    @Autowired 
    DBUtils utils; // issue is with this

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

While doing maven test for entire project and getting the below error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DBUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '*.*.*.dataaccess.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '*.*.*.dataaccess.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

`I have used @Service on DBUtils and @Repository on JpaRepository  but still getting the above error and using springboot is 2.4.1.`

Can anyone please help here?

Comment: The `@Repository` doesn't do a thing. Remove `@ContextConfiguration` or at least the `classes` part of it. ANd make sure your `UserApplication` class, assumed that that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is in a top level package covering everything else.

Comment: Removed and also SpringBootApplication there for main class even though issue is same. Please help me here. @M. Deinum

Comment: As stated make sure that that is in a top level package to cover everything.

Comment: yes, these are under parent package only.   `*.*.* is parent pkg`. @M. Deinum

Comment: Which/what is? What happens if you re move the `@ContextConfiguration` completely?

Comment: Still same error as mentioned above. @M. Deinum

Comment: Then you must be doing things to work around the framework. Please add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated classes and please include the package!.

Comment: Main class added in post now. Please check @M. Deinum

Comment: You did obfuscate things. So if everything is scanned and configured as you said it should work. It doesn't work so you must have configured something, somewhere that disables things or you aren't showing the actual code. Do you have a DB definition else JPA won't work

Comment: Only getting the above error in my Eclipse and others Eclipse this is working fine. but couldn't able to find the issue in my Eclipse yet. can you help on this that what could be this issue in Eclipse? @M. Deinum